# Switching between pages for the same model

Tags: angular, html, typescript

I started working with Angular (currently Angular5) and have a question about switching between pages for the same model.

For example, I have an old project that is based on AngularJS. Let's say we have model Customers. Pages for that model would be:

- page-customers (page with table of existing customers)
- page-new-customer (page with form/wizard for creating new customer)
- page-view-customer (page to see info about existing customer + option
  to update)

Now in AngularJS I would create 3 different routes that send us to these 3 pages. And inside these pages I would include (`ng-include`) form, tables, etc, so I don't repeat too much html and try to re-use it.

My question is, what would be the best/correct way to do this in Angular? Would this mean I have Customers Module with many Components (ex. `PageCustomersComponent`, `PageNewCustomerComponent`, `PageViewCustomerComponent`) and routes that connect to each of them or would these be different Modules (ex. `PageCustomersModule`, etc.) and again routes that connect with them?

Also, if I want to re-use Form for creating Customers in `PageViewCustomer` for update, would this mean I need to create a new Component for this Form? Basically, I'm wondering what would be alternative to AngularJS's `ng-include`.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a number of ways, the way I would do it personally is by using a secondary `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` nested within the `customer.component`.

Inside the `customer.module` I would define routes for the three pages. I would make each of the pages (new customer, view customer and customer table) their own component, and depending on the size of those pages and the methods called within them I would go even further and componentize different parts of the pages, ie Tables, Forms, etc, so they can be reused between the parent components.

This link has a good example of the implementation. https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/child_routes.html

Comment: One major benefit of this that I failed to mention is that if you were to give each of those child pages their own module as well that would make them lazily load.

Comment: Great, this was very helpful. Thank you!